# What regular expression can verify the format of this type of string?

Tags: regex

I need to verify that a string is in a certain format...here are the rules.

- Can contain a colon and/or dot.
- Both the colon and dot are optional
- If a colon and/or dot is specified there must be at least one character to the left and one character to the right of the colon/dot.
- The colon must be before the dot if both are specified
- Only 0 or 1 colon and 0 or 1 dot is allowed
- `AnyString` means a string of one or more unicode characters excluding colon and dot (colon and dot characters are not allowed as part of `AnyString`).

Examples:

Can be...

```
AnyString:AnyString.AnyString
AnyString:AnyString
AnyString.AnyString
AnyString
```

Cannot be...

```
AnyString:.AnyString
AnyString.AnyString:AnyString
AnyString:
AnyString.
:AnyString
.AnyString
```

I have tried lots of different combinations and I am just not good enough at Regular Expressions to get this one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please also post the combinations you tried. Does `Anystring` represent a constant?

Comment: Start with `.+?` and `[^:]+`/`[^.]+` as constructs for "Any[NonEmpty]String"; those should get you "on your way".

Comment: "here are the rules" --- you haven't given any rules, you've just given examples that match and mismatch those rules.

Comment: Yikes...I bet I tried 30 or more...let me go back and see if I can find the ones that were the closest.

Comment: No...`AnyString` is not a constant.

Comment: @zerkms I thought showing the examples would be easier then posting the rules...let me update question.

Comment: @Gene S: showing only them may lead to the answers like: `AnyString:AnyString\.AnyString|AnyString\.AnyString|AnyString` - it's a regular expression that matches all the 3 lines you wanted it to match

Comment: Could you clarify - is `AnyString:AnyString` valid? It sounds like it is, but it's not in your list. Also, please explain what characters are allowed between colons and dots. Just letters? Letters and numbers? Punctuation? Whitespace?

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry...I thought I was being thorough but I can see I was not.  I have updated my rules to indicate what can be between.

Comment: @GeneS: What you've written so far would suggest that `AnyString:..` should be valid - it's got a dot between the colon and a dot, and you don't say that's not allowed. Note that `AnyString.` also meets the currently listed requirements, despite explicitly being in the banned list. Basically, I think you need to think about your requirements in *much* more detail. If you can write down *really, really* rigorous rules, then the regular expression part should be easy.

Comment: Is this a valid description of your requirement? "`Zero or one ("Anystring"s followed by a colon), then zero or one ("Anystring"s followed by a dot), followed by a mandatory "Anystring"`, where `Anystring` is one or more of any character except colons or dots."

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for being patient.  I believe I have written the correct requirements now.

Comment: @Asad Thanks for being patient.  I have clarified the requirements in my question.

Comment: `AnyString:.AnyString` still matches your requirements. The primary problem is that the character to the left or right of the colon or dot does not need to be non-colon or non-dot.

Comment: @Asad Okay, added "excluding colon and dot" to end of last requirement.

Comment: @GeneS: Okay. I've adjusted my answer. See if it fits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, that looks like:

- It definitely starts with one or more non-colon-or-dot characters
- It then *optionally* has a colon followed by one or more non-colon-or-dot characters
- It then *optionally* has a dot followed by one or more non-colon-or-dot characters
- If there are both "colon plus X" and "dot plus X" sections, the colon section must come first

(Note that none of your now-edited-in explanation was present when I wrote the above, so it was just based on the examples.)

So I'd expect that to be a regex like this:

```
^[^.:]+(?::[^.:]+)?(?:\.[^.:]+)?$
```

Notes:

- You'd want to put all of this in a *verbatim string literal* to avoid having to escape the backslashes, e.g.

  ```
  var regex = new Regex(@"^[^.:]+(?::[^.:]+)?(?:\.[^.:]+)?$");
  ```
- `^` matches the start of a string
- `[^.:]` will match any character other than dot or colon
- `+` is the syntax for "at least one"
- `(?:<subexpression>)` is the syntax for a [non-capturing group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#noncapturing_group)
- `\.` is an escaped dot, as `.` means "any character"
- `?` is the syntax for "zero or one" (i.e. optional)
- `$` matches the end of a string

Test code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static readonly Regex regex =
        new Regex(@"^[^.:]+(?::[^.:]+)?(?:\.[^.:]+)?$");

    static void Main()
    {
        AssertValid("AnyString:AnyString.AnyString",
                    "AnyString:AnyString",
                    "AnyString.AnyString",
                    "AnyString");

        AssertInvalid("AnyString:.AnyString",
                      "AnyString.AnyString:AnyString",
                      "AnyString:",
                      "AnyString:..Anystring",
                      "AnyString.",
                      ":AnyString",
                      ".AnyString");
    }

    static void AssertValid(params string[] inputs)
    {
        foreach (var input in inputs)
        {
            if (!regex.IsMatch(input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Expected to match but didn't: {0}",
                                  input);
            }
        }
    }

    static void AssertInvalid(params string[] inputs)
    {
        foreach (var input in inputs)
        {
            if (regex.IsMatch(input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Expected not to match but did: {0}",
                                  input);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also allow something like `AnyString:AnyString`, which doesn't exist in the "can be" group?

Comment: Another item: `if it has both colon and dot - then colon should precede dot`

Comment: @voithos: Yes it would - I hadn't noticed that. Will edit to explain that, but then check whether it's meant to be allowed. (Currently unclear)

Comment: @zerkms: That's already covered by the fact that the `:\L+` group has to come before the `\.\L+` group.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Ah, it seems that it may be allowed, judging from his last update.

Comment: `Can by any string` includes symbols, digits etc.

Comment: @Asad: That wasn't there when I started - I'm trying to get clarification on this...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: yeah, I see that - it was a proposal to add it to your list "Well, that looks like:" :-)

Comment: @zerkms: I was assuming that was implicit on the "it then" :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: oh, it was impossible to get it for the not native. Tricky and indeed it is already there.

Comment: @zerkms: Will make it more explicit, sure.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks.  SO is awesome.  It would have taken me a very long time to come up with this expression.

Comment: @GeneS: Hopefully the notes help you to understand what it's doing :) Let me know if you need any more explanation.

Comment: @JonSkeet Your notes make sense.  I appreciate you taking the time to explain it so I can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic version: `(?:[^:.]+:)?(?:[^:.]+\.)?[^:.]+`. If you define `Anystring` more rigorously, this can be improved.

Your basic requirement looks like it has 3 parts. Zero or one "Anystring"s followed by a colon, then zero or one "Anystring"s followed by a dot, followed by a mandatory "Anystring". This is reflected in the structure of the regex.

Given the information I have, I am considering `[^:.]+` to be a regex that matches an `Anystring`, since the only constraints are

- that it cannot be zero length
- that it cannot contain colons or dots, (which is implied by the fact that a maximum of one colon and one period is allowed)

Comment: Shouldn't your semi-colons be colons?

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[a-z]+[:.]?[a-z]+[:.]?[a-z]+$/i
```

How about that? That one doesn't include digits. What is "AnyString" allowed to contain?

Answer (score 0):

This [appears to](http://rubular.com/) meet all of your listed criteria:

```
^[^.:]+(:[^.:]+)?(\.[^.:]+)?$
```

Note that I assume `AnyString` can literally be anything that doesn't contain a colon or period. Also note that I added begin/end line anchors. You can remove those if you want.

This regex translates in human language to:

- One or more characters that aren't a colon or period.

  - Optionally followed by a colon and then one or more characters that aren't a colon or period.
  - Optionally followed by a period and then one or more characters that aren't a colon or period.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
(.+):(.+)\.(.+)|(.+)\.(.+)
```

Comment: You need to escape the middle dot, and this does not match "Anything:Anything"

Comment: This won't allow `AnyString`. Worse, it WILL allow `AnyString::AnyString`, and other bad inputs

Comment: @CoDeR Your very link shows that it doesn't work for "cvasdvasvasv", which should be allowed according to the OP's criteria.

Answer (score 0):

your match-rule is quite simple if we correctly break it down into logical pieces.

I will take the maximum of possible structure that your strings can contain

that is

```
    TEXT:TEXT.TEXT
```

I'll break that structure as follows:

```
    **TEXT**  then  **:CHARACTER**   then   **TEXT**  then **.CHARACTER**     then    **TEXT**
```

This break-down implies

```
    1. your text starts with a letter, then 0 or more series of letters follow
    2. after it can either contain or not contain a colon which is immediately followed by a letter
    3. then again 0 or more series of letter; pay attention here **0 or more**
    4. then it can contain or not contain a dot immediately followed by a letter
    5. then again 0 or more series of letters; pay attention here **0 or more**
```

In classic regex definition language your regular expression will look like as

```
    [A..Za..z]+  (:[A..Za..z]){0,1}   [A..Za..z]*   (\.[A..Za..z]){0,1}   [A..Za..z]*
```

I have separated the pieces that define the points 1 to 5 above for your ease of reading.
In actual usage there should be no blank spaces in the regex.

Hope this was of assistance.

Cheers.